# Number with leading zeroes gets changed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am calling a javascript function from php using a print statement to print out html code, and I am passing in an integer. However, the value when it is passed in php is not matching the number that the javascript function receives, and I have no clue why.

Here is the php that calls the javascript function:

```
$upc = $items[$i]->GetUPC();
print "upc: " . $upc . "<br/>";

$delete = "<a href='#' onclick='removeFromCart(". $upc .")' ><img src='".$redx."' height='17' width='17' /></a>";
```

The print statement prints out the value: 0011110416605

And on the page, using view source, here is the  tag for this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='removeFromCart(0011110416605)' >
```

Here is the javascript function that is being called:

```
function removeFromCart(itemID){
    var option = document.getElementById("select_cart");
    var selected = option.options[option.selectedIndex].value;

    alert(itemID);

    loadCart(itemID,selected,"","remove");
}
```

The alert box is printing out the number: 1226972549

I could understand if it was removing the leading 0's, but this number is completely different.  Does anyone know why this may be?

Comment: Put quotes around that. `removeFromCart("0011110416605")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JavaScript thinks it is an octal value (because of the leading zero and the lack of digits greater than `7`). The decimal value of octal `0011110416605` is `1226972549`. Example:

```
> var value = 010; //10 in octal
> console.log(value);
> 8  //is 8 in decimal
```

Use a string instead:

```
removeFromCart("0011110416605")
```

Comment: Ok, when I try that, the javascript doesn't even run anymore. I think I did it correctly: this is my console result: <a href="#" onclick="removeFromCart("0011110421111")" >  , and here is my actual code: '<a href="#" onclick="removeFromCart("' . $upc . '")" >'  Did I type something wrong?

Comment: You need to use single quotes or escape the double quotes. You can't use double quotes inside an `onclick` if the attribute value itself is surrounded by double quotes. By the way, it would be way easier to attach events using the DOM API or jQuery.

Comment: I just realized it is because I can't use the same type of quotes around it can I? Considering I am already using single quotes around the whole <a> tag, and double quotes around the function call, how can I get quotes around the inner value without breaking it?

Comment: Ok I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by creating a hidden text called it 'tempcart' then assing value to it with HTML or PHP, it will keep the leading zeros intact as a text string. To make sure, convert it to string if you are passing it thru PHP

HTML:

```
<input type='hidden' id='tempcart' value='0011110416605'>
```

PHP:

```
$itemID = '0011110416605';
$itemID = strval( $itemID );
echo "<input type='hidden' id='tempcart' value=$itemID >";
```

SCRIPT:

```
function removeFromCart() {
var itemID = document.getElementById('tempcart').value;
alert(itemID);
//do whatever...
}
```

This is just sample programming, you need to fit it in your program. I guess Javascript can't pass due to convertion to octal value (because of the leading zero and the lack of digits greater than 7) as @Vivid mention before.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call with including '' quotes

Like onchange="updateLineTotal{$id,'{$po101}')";

Just include it in quotes so it will consider it as string not an integer

Answer (score -2):

I found this issue and I fixed it by using parseInt:

```
itemID = parseInt('0011110416605',10);
```

Comment: This is different – that will give you the number `11110416605`, not the string `"0011110416605"`.

Comment: The question says nothing about the need for an string

Comment: a number can't have leading zeroes.

Comment: Don't know what that has to do with anything. This method returns a valid number based on received string.

Comment: But the OP doesn't want a number, the OP wants the leading zeroes intact (because without leading zeroes the sequence is not a valid UPC).

Comment: That should be clear in the question. Unless you work with UPC (I don't), you can't be aware of that restriction, as it is not specified. Not even "I need to work with UPC", upc is just the name of a variable. The question is about numbers, not strings, leading 0's or formats. Notice the "I could understand if it was removing the leading 0's"